# Vertical alignment in cells (text and pic combination in one table)

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, tkz-euclide

I am making a long two-column table. The first column is allotted for pictures. The second one is for some text. My gol is these two columns to be top-aligned and finish whichever comes first: either vertical size of the picture, or the text. This is my MWE (Please, indulge a poor quality of the picture, it is actually better, just wanted to make this example minimal).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tikz,tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{@{}p{0.618\textwidth}p{0.382\textwidth}@{}}
    \toprule
    Picture title & Text title\\
    \midrule  
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
    \tkzInit[xmin=-1, xmax=6, ymin=-0.5, ymax=2.5]
    \tkzClip
    \tkzDefPoints{0/0/A, 4/2/C, 5/0/B}
    \tkzDefMidPoint(A,B) \tkzGetPoint{M}
    \tkzLabelPoint[above](C){$C$}
    \tkzLabelPoint[below right](B){$B$}
    \tkzLabelPoint[below left](A){$A$}
    \tkzLabelPoint[below](M){$M$}
    \tkzMarkSegment[mark=|](A,M)
    \tkzMarkSegment[mark=|](B,M)
    \tkzMarkSegment[mark=|](C,M)
        \tkzLabelAngle[pos=0.7](B,A,C){$\alpha$}
        \tkzLabelAngle[pos=0.7](A,C,M){$\alpha$}
        \tkzLabelAngle[pos=0.5](A,B,C){$\beta$}
        \tkzLabelAngle[pos=0.5](B,C,M){$\beta$}
    \tkzDrawPolygon[very thick](A,B,C)
    \tkzDrawSegments(C,M)
    \tkzDrawPoints(A,B,C,M)
    \end{tikzpicture} & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. \\
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
    \tkzInit[xmin=-1, xmax=6, ymin=-0.5, ymax=2.5]
    \tkzClip
    \tkzDefPoints{0/0/A, 4/2/C, 5/0/B}
    \tkzDefMidPoint(A,B) \tkzGetPoint{M}
    \tkzLabelPoint[above](C){$C$}
    \tkzLabelPoint[below right](B){$B$}
    \tkzLabelPoint[below left](A){$A$}
    \tkzLabelPoint[below](M){$M$}
    \tkzMarkSegment[mark=|](A,M)
    \tkzMarkSegment[mark=|](B,M)
    \tkzMarkSegment[mark=|](C,M)
    \tkzLabelAngle[pos=0.7](B,A,C){$\alpha$}
    \tkzLabelAngle[pos=0.7](A,C,M){$\alpha$}
    \tkzLabelAngle[pos=0.5](A,B,C){$\beta$}
    \tkzLabelAngle[pos=0.5](B,C,M){$\beta$}
    \tkzDrawPolygon[very thick](A,B,C)
    \tkzDrawSegments(C,M)
    \tkzDrawPoints(A,B,C,M)
    \end{tikzpicture} & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.  \\
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.  & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. \\
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.  & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. \\
    \bottomrule     
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

You see that the text is so to say bottom vertically aligned, but the text is top-aligned. 
[image]

If I change the line

```
\begin{longtable}{@{}p{0.618\textwidth}p{0.382\textwidth}@{}}
```

into

```
\begin{longtable}{@{}b{0.618\textwidth}b{0.382\textwidth}@{}}
```

the result will be:
[image]

Now you see that the picture and the text are bottom aligned (as the code says). I purposely made a text a little bit longer to show it. But there is a white space above the picture. That is NOT what I want. I want the picture to be top aligned regardless of the text length. How to do it. The most likely it is very simple, I just don't know some trick. Your help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `baseline` option of the `tikzpicture` environment to define how the pictures should get aligned. From the [tikz manual](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf) (shortened):

> `/tikz/baseline=`*〈dimension or coordinate or* `default`*〉* (default
>   `0pt`)
>
> Normally, the lower end of the picture is put on the baseline of the
>   surrounding text. For example, when you give the code
>   `\tikz\draw(0,0)circle(.5ex);`, pgf will find out that the lower end
>   of the picture is at -.5ex - 0.2pt and that the upper end is at .5ex +
>   .5pt. Then, the lower end will be put on the baseline. Using this
>   option, you can specify that the picture should be raised or lowered
>   such that the height *〈dimension〉* is on the baseline. Instead of a
>   *〈dimension〉* you can also provide a coordinate in parentheses. Then the effect is to put the baseline on the y-coordinate that the given
>   *〈coordinate〉* has at the end of the picture. This means that, at the end of the picture, the *〈coordinate〉* is evaluated and then the
>   baseline is set to the y-coordinate of the resulting point. Use
>   `baseline=default` to reset the baseline option to its initial configuration.

You probably want to align the label of node `(C)` with the first line of text in the right column. Name the label first using the `name` option of `\tkzLabelPoint`, calling it e.g. `Clabel`, and then use `baseline=(Clabel.base)` to set the baseline of the picture.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tikz,tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{@{}p{0.618\textwidth}p{0.382\textwidth}@{}}
    \toprule
    Picture title & Text title\\
    \midrule  
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1,baseline=(Clabel.base)]
    \tkzInit[xmin=-1, xmax=6, ymin=-0.5, ymax=2.5]
    \tkzClip
    \tkzDefPoints{0/0/A, 4/2/C, 5/0/B}
    \tkzDefMidPoint(A,B) \tkzGetPoint{M}
    \tkzLabelPoint[above,name=Clabel](C){$C$}
    \tkzLabelPoint[below right](B){$B$}
    \tkzLabelPoint[below left](A){$A$}
    \tkzLabelPoint[below](M){$M$}
    \tkzMarkSegment[mark=|](A,M)
    \tkzMarkSegment[mark=|](B,M)
    \tkzMarkSegment[mark=|](C,M)
        \tkzLabelAngle[pos=0.7](B,A,C){$\alpha$}
        \tkzLabelAngle[pos=0.7](A,C,M){$\alpha$}
        \tkzLabelAngle[pos=0.5](A,B,C){$\beta$}
        \tkzLabelAngle[pos=0.5](B,C,M){$\beta$}
    \tkzDrawPolygon[very thick](A,B,C)
    \tkzDrawSegments(C,M)
    \tkzDrawPoints(A,B,C,M)
    \end{tikzpicture} & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. \\
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1,baseline=(Clabel.base)]
    \tkzInit[xmin=-1, xmax=6, ymin=-0.5, ymax=2.5]
    \tkzClip
    \tkzDefPoints{0/0/A, 4/2/C, 5/0/B}
    \tkzDefMidPoint(A,B) \tkzGetPoint{M}
    \tkzLabelPoint[above,name=Clabel](C){$C$}
    \tkzLabelPoint[below right](B){$B$}
    \tkzLabelPoint[below left](A){$A$}
    \tkzLabelPoint[below](M){$M$}
    \tkzMarkSegment[mark=|](A,M)
    \tkzMarkSegment[mark=|](B,M)
    \tkzMarkSegment[mark=|](C,M)
    \tkzLabelAngle[pos=0.7](B,A,C){$\alpha$}
    \tkzLabelAngle[pos=0.7](A,C,M){$\alpha$}
    \tkzLabelAngle[pos=0.5](A,B,C){$\beta$}
    \tkzLabelAngle[pos=0.5](B,C,M){$\beta$}
    \tkzDrawPolygon[very thick](A,B,C)
    \tkzDrawSegments(C,M)
    \tkzDrawPoints(A,B,C,M)
    \end{tikzpicture} & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.  \\
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.  & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. \\
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.  & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. \\
    \bottomrule     
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

[image]