# Right alignment for p{length} box in tabular

Tags: tables

Is there any way to change an alignment in the column if it is set by p{length} in tabular preamble? I want a right aligned column of fixed length.

Same question about a centered column of fixed length.

[Update 12 Sep 2023 when the system indicates there is a duplicate] There is a similar question [here](https://How%20to%20create%20fixed%20width%20table%20columns%20with%20text%20raggedright/centered/raggedleft?). However, that question contains the answer in the question itself. If I knew that the solution is about adding the '\raggedright' I wouldn't ask this question. I believe, My question benefit those who are new in LaTeX and not experience in the entire LaTex arsenal.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Insert one of the commands `\raggedright`, `\centering`, or `\raggedleft` into the parbox depending on whether the paragraph should be typeset flush left, centered, or flush right.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabular}%
  {>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{3.5cm}%
   >{\centering\arraybackslash}p{3.5cm}%
   >{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{3.5cm}%
  }
  \lipsum[1] & \lipsum[2] & \lipsum[3]
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to start it not from the first column? Say, I want the title of the column to be left aligned, but the content to be right aligned. (Actually, I have pictures in the boxes of the first column and I am trying to understand how to align them better. Your solution works and thanks for that, but I don't want it influence the first row) (For pictures, you can have a look to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/337934/vertical-alignment-in-cells-text-and-pic-combination-in-one-table).

Comment: @SergeyBelyaev Use `\multicolomn{1}{l}{Title}` in the title row to get "Title" left aligned.

Comment: This solution worked beautifully for me

Comment: Could you explain what's the role of `arraybackslash` ? I've tried removing this part and haven't observed any difference.

Comment: @Konrad Try to add a second line to the `tabular`. Without `\arraybackslash` in the right column you will get the error `Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr`. `\begin{tabular}` defines `\\ ` as row separator, but `\raggedleft` redefines it and so would break the table. `\arraybackslash` undoes this redefinition.

Comment: This interacts badly with `\newline`; try the content `This spans \newline two lines & This spans \newline three lines \newline or so & This spans \newline four lines \newline which is \newline even more`.