# How to stop justifying cell content and left align horizontally and middle align vertically?

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, overleaf

As you can see on the image, the left column is justifying its content hence add uneven spaces between the content there. I am trying to keep the left column content vertically in the centre and horizontally leftwards.

[image]

I tried adding `\begin{tabular}{>{\RaggedRight}m{3.7cm} m{5cm}` to the following script but it did not work.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{m{3.7cm}| m{5cm}}
\toprule
Sample1                            & Sample2      \\  \midrule
AB\_CDEFG and AB\_CDE       & This is sample text.This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text.  This is sample text.This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text.\\ \midrule
AB\_CD, AB\_CD,AB\_CD and AB\_CD   &  This is sample text.This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text.This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text.\\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\label{table:referent-table}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Appreciate suggestions on how this can be achieved.

Comment: How or where is `\tbl` defined?

Comment: Please add all the packages necessary to compile your code fragment. For example booktabs...

Comment: I updated the question. It should compile now.

Comment: @Mico I removed `\tbl` from the question. It was overriding some of the commands in booktabs package like `\midrule`

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/338009/82917. That question is about `p` columns but the answer is the same for `m` columns: use `>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{...}`.

Comment: Unrelated: `booktabs` does not like vertical lines in columns, as you can see `;-)`

Comment: @campa I actually tired this `>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{...}` but with uppercase `R`, i.e. `\RaggedRight`.  Thank you for pointing this. It works. If you can add this as an answer, otherwise I will remove the question if this is duplicating the other one.

Comment: @campa I don't have a strong preference to use `m{...}` as far as I can left align and centre vertically. When I tried `{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{3.5cm} m{5.0cm}}` it works but the content is not vertically centred but `{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{3.5cm} m{5.0cm}}` works well. So I don't think the question you linked directly answer my question but it does help indeed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could load the `ragged2e` package and use its `\RaggedRight` instruction to achieve your formatting objective. While you're at it, you might also apply `\RaggedRight` to the second column.

Do note that `\RaggedRight` permits hyphenation of words in the cells. If you wish to suppress hyphenation as well, just change `\RaggedRight` to `\raggedright\arraybackslash`.

[image]

Aside: I can't help but admire the typographic river that flows streight through the right-hand cells. :-)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,booktabs,ragged2e}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\caption{Example of a table\strut} 
\label{table:referent-table}

\centering % <-- don't forget this instruction

\begin{tabular}{@{} >{\RaggedRight}m{3.7cm} >{\RaggedRight}m{5.0cm} @{}}
\toprule
Sample1 & Sample2 \\  
\midrule
AB\_CDE, AB\_CDE and AB\_CDE       
& This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text. \\ 
\midrule
AB\_CD, AB\_CD, AB\_CD and AB\_CD   
& This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text. \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry for the typographic river, I thought it is easier to use it to show the vertical centre alignment I needed. And I liked that you have added the `\caption` and `\label` which I have removed from my question snippet. :-)